# Text change won't trigger an event

Tags: html, angular

I have: `<input type="text" id="help-text" [(ngModel)]="fileName" disabled>`, and I'm curious to find how can I trigger an event if 'fileName' changed in Angular. `(change)="onChange()"` does not seem to be working and a couple of pre-defined jquery scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove disabled attribute and use `ngModelChange`

```
<input type="text" id="help-text" [(ngModel)]="fileName" (ngModelChange)="modelChanged($event)">
```